# How to edit input type button with CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

```
<input type="button" class="wcSubmitButton" value="Lähetä">
```

How to edit this with css, i want to change the button's color? Feels like i've tried every possible solution i have found on. What i am missing?

Comment: What solutions have you tried? It would also help if you indicated what you are exactly trying to edit.

Comment: "How to edit this with css"  - what do you want to edit it to?

Comment: Trying to change the buttons color.

Answer (score 0):

Please give more info.What have you tried? If you address it in a CSS stylesheet

.wcSubmitButton {
*some CSS styles ....*
}

still not working? Have you tried with an id ? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yeah trying to address it in css so i could change the buttons color. I have tried .wcSubmitButton

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it with HTML and CSS.

```css
#test{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<input id = "test" type="button" class="wcSubmitButton" value="Lähetä">
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS cannot modify property values, such as `type`. It was not designed to do that. You can either modify the HTML itself or use DOM through JavaScript or jQuery. You can, however, modify the element *name*, using the CSS3 `appearance` property, [although it has little support and requires prefixes.](https://caniuse.com/?search=appearance) Here's an example:

```
button {
   appearance: span;
}
```